# Hanoi towers recursive expression for EVERY algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion, induction

What the recursive algorithm for moving $n$ disks says, is:

1. If $n > 1$, move $n-1$ discs from A to B.
2. Move the $n$th disk from A to C.
3. If $n > 1$, move $n-1$ discs from B to C.

Let $T_n$ be the number of moves for moving n disks.

We have 
$
T_n=2T_{n-1}+1 , T_1=1 $, so $T_n=2^n-1, n \geq 1 $

> Is it correct to say that **for every algorithm** solving the Hanoi Towers problem, it is true that
>   $$
> T_n=2T_{n-1}+c
> $$
>   So we would need to know $c$ (number of moves for moving the last disk from A to C) and some other $T_i$, in order to  calculate $T_ n$ for every $n$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's hard to make a statement about _every_ algorithm for a problem: what about the algorithm that acts exactly like yours, except that if $n=69105$, it first moves a single disk back and forth seventy thousand times? Now $T_{69105}$ isn't perfectly predictable from $T_{69104}$.

Comment: Is this the 3-pegs variant? If so, your approach is the one based on divide-and-conquer which is known to be optimal,

Comment: Here's another detailed answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464354/hanoi-towers-recursive-expression-for-every-algorithm